# sed command is waiting at end of the line in given file

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I am trying to replace a string between two section in a ini file. I am using sed command, I am able to achieve what I want but after executing the sed command, its replacing text and waiting for input at the end of the file in the console.

My ini file is

```
[platform]
security=http://security:8080/
referral=http://mindapp:8000/
catalog=http://catalog:8080/
workorder=http://workorder:8080/
assets=http://assets:8080/
provider=http://provider:8080/

[app]
name=express
ssl=false
port=8080
hostname=0.0.0.0
```

in the above file I am trying to add namespace.cluster.svc.local before :8080 using below command.

```
sed -n -e '/\[platform\]/,/\[app\]/p' | sed -e '1d;$d' | sed 's/:/\.das-ci.svc.cluster.local&/2g' secrets.ini
```

Is there any way we can avoid waiting after executing the command?

Comment: try `sed <secrets.ini -n -e '...' | sed ... | sed ...` Command line are executed from left to right, *input* have to be read by 1st command!

Comment: no luck its ignoring other section in ini file

Comment: And why not simply: `sed -ne 's/:/\.das-ci.svc.cluster.local&/2p' secrets.ini ` (without any pipe `|`)!

Comment: In other sections i have some other url's which should not be changed.  I need to change in specific section only.

Comment: Then try this: `sed -e '/^\[platform\]/,/^\[/s/:/\.das-ci.svc.cluster.local&/2' secrets.ini`

Comment: Adding g is working finally sed -e '/\[platform\]/,/^$/s/:/\.das-ci.svc.cluster.local&/2g' secrets.ini   Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Below command is working fine.

```
sed -e '/\[platform\]/,/^$/s/:/\.das-ci.svc.cluster.local&/2g' secrets.ini
```

thank you @f-hauri-give-up-github

Answer (score 0):

The first command waits fro stdin,
do this instead

```
sed -n -e '/\[platform\]/,/\[app\]/p'  secrets.ini  | sed -e '1d;$d' | sed 's/:/\.das-ci.svc.cluster.local&/2g'
```

You should do it invoking `sed` only once though.

Comment: I have used this route but its replacing the values as required but its ignoring other sections in the file.

Comment: @Venkatesh That's because the first command deletes everything other than that one section. I think you want to pass other sections unchanged, which is something entirely different.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`

```
sed -n '/\[platform]/,/\[app]/{//!s/:/.das-ci.svc.cluster.local&/2p}' input_file
security=http://security.das-ci.svc.cluster.local:8080/
referral=http://mindapp.das-ci.svc.cluster.local:8000/
catalog=http://catalog.das-ci.svc.cluster.local:8080/
workorder=http://workorder.das-ci.svc.cluster.local:8080/
assets=http://assets.das-ci.svc.cluster.local:8080/
provider=http://provider.das-ci.svc.cluster.local:8080/
```

Comment: curly brackets `{ ... }`  are useless because there is only 1 command,  `//!` is useless, as none of `[platform]` , or `[next section]` would match `:` ;-)